# Why the "-1" in "dbus-1" for D-Bus directories?

Tags: d-bus

Most of the directories related to D-Bus append `-1` to the name: `/etc/dbus-1`, `/usr/share/dbus-1`, etc. (but not `/var/lib/dbus`, for some reason).  What is the meaning/rationale behind `-1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-1` reflects the API version, and is used in directory names to support parallel installations of a D-Bus 1 implementation and a hypothetical D-Bus 2 implementation (or any other combination).

This is hinted at by the old [changelog](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/dbus/dbus/tree/ChangeLog.pre-1-0#n10644):

> - dbus-1.pc.in, dbus-glib-1.pc.in: rename these from
>         dbus-1.0.pc.in, dbus-glib-1.0.pc.in. As these change with the
>         parallel install API version, not with the D-BUS package version.

(It's not referring to `dbus-1` folder names but I think the same reasoning applies there...)

It's an example of D-Bus following its own advice; from the [specification](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-protocol-names):

> It is also a good idea to include the major version of the interface in the name, and increment it if incompatible changes are made; this way, a single object can implement several versions of an interface in parallel, if necessary.